# Check whether a number (given number = 100), is greater than or equal to 100, less than 100 and greater than 50, or less than or equal to 50

Tags: kotlin

the question here I am asking is whether we can use the when statement which is an expression body of nested if statements all the time in kotlin.

Comment: Please provide us your previous attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun check(num: Int) = when {
    num >= 100 -> "$num is greater than or equal to 100"
    num > 50 -> "$num is less than 100 and greater than 50"
    else -> "$num is less than or equal to 50"
}

fun main() {
    println(check(200))
    println(check(100))
    println(check(70))
    println(check(51))
    println(check(50))
    println(check(30))
}
```

Output:

```
200 is greater than or equal to 100
100 is greater than or equal to 100
70 is less than 100 and greater than 50
51 is less than 100 and greater than 50
50 is less than or equal to 50
30 is less than or equal to 50
```